# How to convert this 220V AC input inductive charger to 127V AC input?

Tags: transformer, charger, coil, inductive, wireless-charging

My friend bought a device that has wireless charging, but in my country, in the region I live,  the AC voltage is 127V , and she received (a long ago) by mistake a 220V AC input version.

She never got to make it work and she didn't know it was sent to her the wrong version.

I happen to have bought just now the same device, but mine was sent correctly to 127V AC Input, and works correctly.

So I opened the base of her charger and mine, and the (chinese) circuits are similar.

220V AC Input charger below:

[image: 220V Input Inductive Charger]

127V AC Input charger below:

[image]

In hers, the 220V AC input part has a half bridge rectifier design, with two 7.5K higher wattage resistors in parallel, and mine, the 127VAC version, it has only a full bridge rectifier with no resistors at the input part of the charger.

The other part of the circuit, the switching part, seems similar also , the only difference I saw is that in hers, the two resistors (R3 and R2) are 1K and 1M, and in mine they are (R1 and R2)  2K2 and 2M2. The transistors are NPN, but in hers it's the NPN MJE1003 and in mine it's the A42. The capacitors are all the same in both boards, even the 4.7UF electrolytic one at the input part.

So, is there a simple way to "convert" her circuit to work with 127V? If I just change the both resistors (1K and 1M to 2K2 and 2M2) be enough?  Or changing those two bigger 7.5K resistors to other values? Maybe removing one of them?

I could add a full wave bridge rectifier in her circuit also, and get rid of those two resistors just like in mine also.

I've drawn her circuit using falstad below, but I don't know the coil value. I put 10uH.

[image: Fasltad circuit]

If more info is needed, just ask!

Thanks!

Comment: there seem to be many differences. do both even use the same power coil?

Comment: The capacitors are all the same. The transistors are different but both high voltage NPN ones. The input part is different, as I said. The coils seems visually to be the same... I can't measure inductance directly... Is there any other way to compare the coils?

Comment: same wire, same bulk, probably the same.

Answer (score 0):

Measure the voltage (carefully! - shock hazard) across the 4.7 µF capacitor in your *working* charger, and across the other charger, when plugged into the 127 VAC line.

From the looks of your schematic, I'd expect the voltage on the cap in the 220 VAC charger to be about half that in yours.

If that is the case, replace the two resistors and diode with four diodes (or a packaged full wave bridge).

**N.B.**

- There does not appear to be a fuse in either circuit. You might add a fuse, as simple as some thin (26 or 28 AWG, 0.4 or 0.3 mm dia) magnet wire, to reduce the risk of fire.
- There is no isolation from the AC mains other than the case around the circuit. Hopefully, it is double insulated, though since it's inductively coupled, the device being charged would not be "hot".